# How to organize a list of dates

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of daily measurements taken on given dates, where the measurements follow the dates:

```
lis = {"a", "b", "October", "01", "2021", "c", "d", "October", "1", "2021","e", "October", "2", "2021", "f"}
```

I would like to organize these measurements as discrete list members as follows:

```
res = {{DateObject[{2021,10,1}],"c","d"},{DateObject[{2021,10,1}],"e"},{DateObject[{2021,10,2}],"f"}}
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Sounds like an awful format. Do you know that there will always be two entries at the front to discard? Can you get the data in a better format to start with?

Comment: It is a horrible format, I totally agree (that's why I'm here :)  There can be any number of entries to discard at the front.

Comment: Based on the subject, maybe take one to a movie, another bowling,...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematica solutions fit into many categories and take their readers through different abstract states (pause, admiration, disbelief, bewilderment etc). I present a step by step solution mostly for new learners. Given:

```
lis = {"a", "b", "October", "01", "2021", "c", "d", "October", "1", 
  "2021", "e", "October", "2", "2021", "f"}
```

Define months; Remember that month strings could be shortened as "Jan", "Feb" etc or these could be lower case or in another language, but let's work with standard English strings for now:

```
months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}

morules = MapThread[Rule, {months, Range[12]}]
```

> ```
> {"January" -> 1, "February" -> 2, "March" -> 3, "April" -> 4, 
>  "May" -> 5, "June" -> 6, "July" -> 7, "August" -> 8, 
>  "September" -> 9, "October" -> 10, "November" -> 11, 
>  "December" -> 12}
> ```

Define a monthQ function to see if an input string is a month. Test the function:

```
monthQ[s_String] := MemberQ[months, s]
monthQ[#] & /@ {"Banana", "October", "April", "Carrot"}
```

> ```
> {False, True, True, False}
> ```

**Main solution starts here-----------**

Since "October" is the marker where things need to be split, find positions where it (or another month name string) occurs.

```
pos = Position[MemberQ[months, #] & /@ lis, True]
```

> {{3}, {8}, {12}}

Now insert a marker at these positions where split will happen, (* U2702 = ✂ *)

```
lis2 = Insert[lis, "✂", pos]
```

> ```
> {"a", "b", "✂", "October", "01", "2021", "c", "d", "✂", "October", \
> "1", "2021", "e", "✂", "October", "2", "2021", "f"}
> ```

```
lis2a = SequenceSplit[lis2, {"✂"}]

{{"a", "b"}, {"October", "01", "2021", "c", "d"}, {"October", "1", 
  "2021", "e"}, {"October", "2", "2021", "f"}}
```

The first list could be without a month marker. I will pretend that there could be others as a result of some other processing. Select only those lists that have a month-string as their first element.

```
lis3 = Select[lis2a, monthQ[First[#]] &]

{{"October", "01", "2021", "c", "d"}, {"October", "1", "2021", 
  "e"}, {"October", "2", "2021", "f"}}
```

Now write a utility function to parse the first three members of each list as a date object. Be as simple and modular as possible, as such juxtapositions can change.

```
dobjparse[k_List] := Module[{t1, t2, t3},
  t1 = ToExpression[(k[[1]] /. morules)];
  (*Echo[t1];*)
  t2 = ToExpression[k[[2]]];
  (*Echo[t2];*)
  t3 = ToExpression[k[[3]]];
  (*Echo[t3];*)
  DateObject[{t3, t1, t2}]
  ]
```

Now apply this utility function to appropriate sections of `lis3` and keep the rest of the sublist elements:

```
{dobjparse[#[[1 ;; 3]]], Sequence @@ #[[4 ;; -1]]} & /@ lis3
```

This solution has added nothing new compared to Bob Hanlon's elegant and concise solution; however, the advantage of this solution is that it is modular and can be modified by users at various Mma skill levels should they need to.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
   "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

monthRule = Thread[months -> Range[12]];

monthQ[mo_String] := MemberQ[months, mo]

lis = {"a", "b", "October", "01", "2021", "c", "d", "October", "1", 
   "2021", "e", "October", "2", "2021", "f"};
```

Use [`SequenceCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html) to select the groupings. Then format the groupings.

```
lis2 = {DateObject[#[[1 ;; 3]] /. monthRule // ToExpression // 
      RotateRight], Sequence @@ #[[4 ;;]]} & /@ 
  SequenceCases[lis, { _?monthQ, _?(! monthQ[#] &) ..}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bob Hanlon and @kglr!  For these solutions to work, I need to first clean up the list by somehow deleting all list elements that appear before the first occurrence of the pattern: {___,"Saturday","October","02","2021",___} in the list.  Again thx for ideas.

Comment: @Suite401 - If you mean you want to delete all items prior to `Oct 2, 2021` use `Select[lis2, DateDifference[DateObject[{2021, 10, 2}], #[[1]]] > Quantity[-1, "day"] &]`

Comment: @Suite401, In the solution I have posted, it is quite easy to filter the first sublist if it doesn't contain the desired pattern.

Comment: Thank you @Syed

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll[reOrg]
reOrg = {DateObject @ DateString @ StringRiffle[{#, #2, #3}, "/"], ##4} &;

ipdQ = Internal`PossibleDateQ;

SequenceCases[lis, 
 p : {_?ipdQ, _, _?ipdQ, Except[_?ipdQ] ..} :> reOrg @@ p]
```

> [image]

Alternatively,

```
reOrg @@@ SequenceCases[lis, {_?ipdQ, _, _?ipdQ, Except[_?ipdQ] ..}]
```

> [image]